# Проверка введенной пользователем строки в Entry на соответствие tkinter Python3

Tags: python-3.x, gui, tkinter

Пользователь вводит строку в Entry, после чего с помощью get() получаем введённую строку и проверяем равна ли она заранее заданной строке. Но проблема в том что даже если строка из Entry полностью аналогична необходимой то программа не переходит в тело условия. Я совсем не понимаю почему. Пожалуйста помогите.

```
most = Entry(root, bg='white', width=80, bd=0, fg='#01213d', font=('Arial', 8, 'bold'))
most.place(x=63, y=89)
if most.get().lower() == 'bridge':
    e_cl = e_cl + 1
```

Comment: у вас не происходит сигнал т.е. когда вы запускаете программу она сразу проверяет есть ли в `most` что то  и если нету то продолжает работу дальше

Comment: У вас условие выполнится задолго до того, как пользователь что-либо введёт. Нужно задать обработчик изменения значения `Entry`.

Comment: как это можно пофиксить?@Twiss @SergeyGornostaev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно через кнопку подать сигнал на функцию после чего в ней будет обрабатываться ваш запрос

```
from tkinter import *

def button_entry():
    if most.get().lower() == 'bridge':
        e_cl = 1
        e_cl = e_cl + 1
        print(e_cl)

root = Tk()
most = Entry(root, bg='white', width=80, bd=0, fg='#01213d', font=('Arial', 8, 'bold'))
most.grid()
button = Button(root, text='нажми', command=button_entry).grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Уже догадался, но спасибо